# Android app layout issue: elements appear in the corner of the screen in phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm very new to Android app developing. I've designed the layout using drag and drop of elements. But when I run this app in the mobile all the elements of the app are gathered in the top left corner of the display. I've added screenshot how I designed the layout

[image: how I designed]

and how it appears on my mobile screen.

[image: how it appears]

Here the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jyotirmoy.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Enter any text"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text will be displayed here:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="307dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-35dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Print"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="122dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here you don't use constrains for your views when using **ConstraintLayout** you should put constrains for your views to appear as you designed
the correct layout will be like there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Enter any text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Print"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use whole layout inside `LinearLayout`;

```
 <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Enter any text"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Print"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-250dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your text will be displayed here:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="307dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-35dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="Print"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="122dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Furthermore it destroys the purpose of the `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead of ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is as simple as this then there's no need to use `ConstraintLayout`. Check out [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) where you could set the orientation of the items. Or [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) where you have more flexibility with items.

Meanwhile here's a solution with `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter any text"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="print"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your text will appear here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```